# asp.net Entity Data Model doesn't have submitChanges

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I start to work with LINQ, but my DbContext doesn't have the submitChanges method. It should be default in the class. Right?

```
    using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

public partial class LibraryEntities : DbContext
{
    public LibraryEntities()
        : base("name=LibraryEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<MSreplication_options> MSreplication_options { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<spt_fallback_db> spt_fallback_db { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<spt_fallback_dev> spt_fallback_dev { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<spt_fallback_usg> spt_fallback_usg { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<spt_monitor> spt_monitor { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to call the SubmitChanges, it says that the method does not exist. Does anyone know why?

```
int id = (int)HttpContext.Current.Session["userId"];

    var query = (from u in db.Users
                 where u.Id == id
                 select u).FirstOrDefault();

    query.FirstName = firstNameModal.Text;

    db.SubmitChanges();
```

Answer (score 2):

The method you're looking for is called `SaveChanges`.

Comment: I tried with SaveChanges(), but it didn't change in the database

Comment: That is another issue, but the method you want is definitely `SaveChanges`.

Comment: Because I google it, and most of the tutorials say that I have to use SubmitChanges in order to commit into the database

Comment: `SubmitChanges` is from Linq To Sql, while `SaveChanges` is the Entity Framework version. Looks like you may have been following some Linq To Sql guides.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. So, using Entity Framework how can I commit my changes into the database?

Comment: That should be it. Does it throw an exception? It may be worth asking another question for this other issue.

Comment: It doesn't throw an exception. But the value of my asp:TextBox never change. I load the value from the DB and set in the TextBox.Text. Later the user change the value and click on Save, but in the save button method the value still the same that was loaded from the DB. It doesn't get the value entered by the User.

Comment: cant find both :(